# How to implement a responsive map image with markers

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have the following code that displays a map with absolutely positioned markers. 
It works well but I have a new requirement for this to be responsive to changes in screen size (mobile optimised).

Is it possible to achieve this such that the markers adjust to their correct positions, in this case on Alaska and Greenland, as the screen resizes (horizontally).

```css
.map-marker {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    text-decoration:none;
  }
  .map-marker span {
    position:relative;
    z-index: 2;
    color:#fff;
  }
  .map-marker:before {
    content: "\f111";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    position: relative;
    right: -14px;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  #one {
    top: 70px;
    left: 20px;
  }

  #two {
    top: 50px;
    left: 260px;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="map_container">
  <img src="http://geology.com/world/world-map-clickable.gif" />
  <a href="#" id="one" class="map-marker">
    <span aria-hidden="true">1</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#" id="two" class="map-marker">
    <span aria-hidden="true">2</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Use percentage-based positioning.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible using the pseudo-element method above to achieve numbering with Font-Awsome. I have tried before, but I'm happy to be educated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a few things:

- `position:relative;display:inline-block;` on `.map_container`, so any `top` and `left` attributes on the markers are relative to this wrapper. the `display` is added so it always has the width of its contents (hence of the `<img>`) - otherwise on large displays it would be larger than the image and the markers would be offset. If you want `display:block` on it, just wrap it inside a `<div>`.
- `max-width:100%` on the `<img>` element to make it shrink on mobile to max available width.
- play a bit with percentages until you get it right.

Here's the output:

```css
.map_container {
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.map_container img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.map-marker {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    text-decoration:none;
  }
  .map-marker span {
    position:relative;
    color:#fff;
  }
  .map-marker:before {
    content: "\f111";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
  #one {
    top: 17%;
    left: 4%;
  }

  #two {
    top: 12%;
    left: 34%;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="map_container">
  <img src="http://geology.com/world/world-map-clickable.gif" />
  <a href="#" id="one" class="map-marker">
    <span aria-hidden="true">1</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#" id="two" class="map-marker">
    <span aria-hidden="true">2</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Note: I also changed the way you centered your pins, because, being offset from center, they appeared to be moving on map while scaling browser.

Comment: Perfect solution and with additional benefits. Much appreciated!